# I can't execute SSH command line

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, ovh

I pushed my Laravel project on my OVH server through SFTP.

And now I'm trying to use command lines on my ssh connection, but something doesn't work, it looks like I am in a text editor. When I try commands, connection will close.

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> ssh xxxxx
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\xxx/.ssh/id_rsa_xxx':
Welcome to OVH
pwd
ls
Connection to ssh.cluster0xx.hosting.ovh.net closed.
```

What did I miss?

I worked on Linux, so developing on Windows is quite new for me.
I'm using PowerShell 7.1.4 & Windows 10.

Comment: This looks to be a problem with your login shell, your connection, or the openssh client. The SSH command is an executable, and not a cmdlet. Therefore, this is most likely not caused by PowerShell. You can confirm this by using the ssh command in Command Prompt or by downloading an external client like PuTTy

Comment: Thank you ! It was a misunderstanding on my part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your FTP user settings on the server side.

In your case, the SSH connection setting is on `SFTP` but you need to change it to `Enable` or `ON`.

[image of ovh ssh user settings (fr)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdpmF.png).

Wait a few minutes that the changes on the server applies, and then you can connect using your shell with the command `ssh username@server` *(remplace username and server with your data)*.